# I'm using jQuery How can I enable all keyboard keys when after i disable them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jQuery for this exercise. I have a text area with class .postText I'm setting condition when the character count reaches 0 from 140 making all keyboard keys disabled with e.preventDefault() apart from the backspace 8. Then what I want after I delete 1 letter and it is back to remaining character count to 1 I want all keyboard keys to be enabled again how do i do that?

my code

```
$('.postText').on('keyup', event => {
  let post = $(event.currentTarget).val();
  let remaining = 140 - post.length;
  if (remaining <= 5) {
    $('.wordcount').addClass('red'); // just making the text red 
  } else {
    $('.wordcount').removeClass('red');
  }

  if (remaining == 0) {
    $('.postText').on('keydown', e => {
      if (e.keyCode !== 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }); // how can I enable all the keyboard keys back after this here?
  }
  $('.characters').html(remaining);
});
```

Comment: Don't add event listeners inside other event listeners. They get added, they don't replace.

Comment: just don't do it, there is a `maxlength` attributes that does it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put one event handler inside another. Use two event handlers, and have them both check their appropriate conditions.

```js
const maxText = 10;

$('.postText').on('keyup', event => {
  let post = $(event.currentTarget).val();
  let remaining = maxText - post.length;
  if (remaining <= 5) {
    $('.wordcount').addClass('red'); // just making the text red 
  } else {
    $('.wordcount').removeClass('red');
  }
  $('.characters').html(remaining);
});

$('.postText').on('keydown', e => {
  let post = $(e.currentTarget).val();
  let remaining = maxText - post.length;
  if (remaining == 0 && e.keyCode !== 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="postText"></textarea>
<div class="wordcount">Remaining: <span class="characters">0</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks works now nice to see I wasn't far off

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the length of the value on keydown and prevent the event if the length is at its maximum.

```js
let maxLength = 10;

$("textarea").on("keydown", function(e){
  if($(this).val().length >= maxLength && e.keyCode != 8)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, maxLength));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This textarea accepts a maximum of 10 characters.</p>
<textarea></textarea>
```